# How do I control which NPCs live where?

Tags: terraria

An exciting new feature is described in the [1.1 patch notes](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/welcome-to-terraria-1-1.64684/):

> - There is a new NPC housing interface that can be used to assign living areas to NPC’s. This interface will also tell you if a room is missing any requirements.

How can this interface be accessed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you make an NPC move house?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23662/how-can-you-make-an-npc-move-house)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, I think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access this interface from the inventory menu. Near the PVP controls, just above the equipment grid, there is a small house. When you click it, you'll toggle the equipment to the housing interface.

You'll then be able to use the different NPCs faces to assign them a room, or the question mark to check if a room is able to house a NPC.

Answer (score 0):

make 1 more valid house then use the Housing interface to move them around then deconstruct the extra house or get a new NPC for it