# How do you get NPC's to go inside their houses?

Tags: terraria

In Terraria, when a new NPC arrives, I see my friends NPC's to go inside like a charm. For me though, I have walked away from them, gone to the underworld away from them, done every little tip people have given me, but the NPC's NEVER spawn inside my house. I have to manually make a staircase for them to walk inside.Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried designating rooms to specific NPC's? The latest version of Terraria added a feature in the menu that lets you flag which rooms belong to which NPC's. The way to do this can be found here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/39783/10204.

Comment: I did, I put a red flag up with the NPC's head, but he's still stuck in a cave...

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple answer, I just saved-signed out and logged back in. They were in their rooms where they belonged!

Answer (score 2):

It happened also to me. The Guide and the Nurse decided to go hiking for no apparent reason. The way I made them go into their houses? Simply put, I paved them the way in. First I locked them in a cave, then I made a way of little steps for them to come to my house. That's all. For me it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble assigning rooms to NPCs too. It turned out to be because the house I was attempting to assign them was too close to some Corruption. Try getting rid of any Ebonstone or vile/corrupt grass you have nearby.

Also note that NPCs won't share a home with each other.

Thirdly note that the NPCs will "teleport" around if you leave the area for awhile and come back. This may be what you're looking for if you're having trouble leading them somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

NPCs teleport to their rooms at night when they are outside everyone's view area

Comment: Unless you've looked at the code, how can you know?  Please, back up your statements with verifiable proof.

Comment: @MBraedley I think the they mean is that if you leave your house to go exploring, when you come back, they should respawn on your screen in their own rooms.

Answer (score 1):

Go somewhere where you're not gonna see them, like mining, for a half an hour or so and they'll most likely be back in their rooms. And also try to designate rooms to the NPCs by going into the inventory and on the right side, beside your equipment etc, click on the little house and click on an NPC icon, and clicking on a room

Answer (score 1):

I find that if you build a staircase of wooden platforms at the side of your house, with wooden platforms between each floor, the NPCs just walk up it to their room. Some may be a bit slow about it, but it always works. Sorry if I didn't explain it very well however.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened with me. I had to carefully pave a path for him and block the way behind him so he couldn't go back when he went forward . I made it so he only had to jump up one block at a time. It takes a while but it works.

Answer (score -1):

Just be out at night for like 3 minutes and they should go back. But, in that 3 minutes don't look at the NPCs. Keep them out of screen sight.

Answer (score -2):

Keep all of your items in a chest and die, it will take your npc back to their room and you do not lose money if you put it in the chest.